# Task from task scheduler does not start at start ec2 instance without login

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled EC2 instance to start every morning using Lambda. I have configured some task in task scheduler which I want it to run once EC2 is up however task wont get triggered until I login to EC2 instance. I want my task scheduler runs automatically at defined time without login to EC2 instance. Its a windows instance.

I tried configuring task without login but it doesn’t invoke.

Answer (score 1):

To run a script every time an Amazon EC2 instance starts, simply add the script to this directory:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

Most Amazon EC2 AMIs have `cloud-init` installed. It is responsible for running scripts from User Data. It will also check the above directory and run any scripts it finds there. This does not require a user to login.

Comment: But I need Time Based scheduler like task scheduler

Comment: You mentioned that you have already set a schedule on the AWS Lambda function to start the instance. Do you still need a time-based scheduler on the instance itself, or should it always run the same code every time the instance starts?

Comment: Created lambda function just to start the instance. Actually there are few programs which run after every half an hour . For eg. at 8 am program X runs, at 8:30 am program Y runs.

Comment: In that case, @jhashimoto's answer seems most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose the `Run whether user is logged on or not` option of the task?

[Fix Scheduled Task Won’t Run for .BAT File](https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/fix-scheduled-task-wont-run-bat-file/)

> Next, you have to choose the Run whether user is logged on or not option